# seg fault caused by malloc and sscanf in a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, segmentation-fault

I want to open a text file (see below), read the first int in every line and store it in an array, but I get an segmentation fault. I got rid of all gcc warnings, I read through several tutorials I found on the net and searched stackoverflow for solutions, but I could't make out, what I am doing wrong.

It works when I have everything in the main function (see example 1), but not when I transfer it to second function (see example 2 further down). In example 2 I get, when I interpret gdb correctly a seg fault at `sscanf (line,"%i",classes[i]);`.

I'm afraid, it could be something trivial, but I already wasted one day on it.

Thanks in advance.

**[Example 1] Even though that works with everything in main:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

const int LENGTH = 1024;

int main() {
  char *filename="somedatafile.txt";
  int *classes;
  int lines;      
  FILE *pfile = NULL; 
  char line[LENGTH];
  pfile=fopen(filename,"r");
  int numlines=0;
  char *p;

  while(fgets(line,LENGTH,pfile)){
    numlines++;
  }

  rewind(pfile);

  classes=(int *)malloc(numlines*sizeof(int));
  if(classes == NULL){
    printf("\nMemory error.");
    exit(1);
  }
  int i=0;
  while(fgets(line,LENGTH,pfile)){
    printf("\n");
    p = strtok (line," ");
    p = strtok (NULL, ", ");
    sscanf (line,"%i",&classes[i]);
    i++;
  }
  fclose(pfile);
  return 1;
}
```

**[Example 2] This does not with the functionality transfered to a function:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

const int LENGTH = 1024;

void read_data(int **classes,int *lines, char *filename){
  FILE *pfile = NULL; 
  char line[LENGTH];
  pfile=fopen(filename,"r");
  int numlines=0;
  char *p;

  while(fgets(line,LENGTH,pfile)){
    numlines++;
  }

  rewind(pfile);

  * classes=(int *)malloc(numlines*sizeof(int));
  if(*classes == NULL){
    printf("\nMemory error.");
    exit(1);
  }
  int i=0;
  while(fgets(line,LENGTH,pfile)){
    printf("\n");
    p = strtok (line," ");
    p = strtok (NULL, ", ");
    sscanf (line,"%i",classes[i]);
    i++;
  }
  fclose(pfile);
  *lines=numlines;
}  

int main() {
  char *filename="somedatafile.txt";
  int *classes;
  int lines;

  read_data(&classes, &lines,filename) ;
  for(int i=0;i<lines;i++){
    printf("\nclasses[i]=%i",classes[i]);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

**[Content of somedatafile.txt]**

```
50 21 77 0 28 0 27 48 22 2
55 0 92 0 0 26 36 92 56 4
53 0 82 0 52 -5 29 30 2 1
37 0 76 0 28 18 40 48 8 1
37 0 79 0 34 -26 43 46 2 1
85 0 88 -4 6 1 3 83 80 5
56 0 81 0 -4 11 25 86 62 4
55 -1 95 -3 54 -4 40 41 2 1
53 8 77 0 28 0 23 48 24 4
37 0 101 -7 28 0 64 73 8 1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
 sscanf (line,"%i",classes[i]);
```

is probably wrong. You need to dereference there too, try:

```
 sscanf (line,"%i", &(*classes)[i]);
```

This is because `classes` is a pointer to an array of integers. You want the address of one of those integers, so that `sscanf()` can write the parsed number there. Therefore, you must first dereference `classes` to get the array, then say that you want the address of element number `i` in that array.

You could also use

```
 sscanf (line,"%i", *classes + i);
```

Which might be clearer, depending on how comfortable you are with these things.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! But I have never seen &(*foo)[bar] before. It looks like it should be the same as foo[bar], but it is obviously not. What does it mean?

Comment: `classes[i]` is an `int *`; `(*classes)` is also an `int *`, `(*classes)[i]` is an `int`, and `&(*classes)[i]` is the address of that `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're applying the [] operator to an int* in the first case and an int** in the second.  The int** is like a 2d array, when you use the [] operator in conjunction with the int** you are indexing into an array of int*.  In your case this is not what you want, because you only initialize the first the first entry in this array.  So when you access classes[1] it will crash because it's uninitialized.  You could avoid yourself this confusion by passing in the pointer as a reference instead of a double pointer:

```
int*& classes instead of int** classes
```

Then you could use the same code as from your main function.